# In C, why is my program stuck on wait() when trying to pipe multiple commands?

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I'm writing a simple program to pipe between three commands. For each command, I fork a child and call execvp in it, while the parent waits for execvp to finish (Note since I fork three times, I call wait(NULL) three times)

I've created two pipes, pipe_A and pipe_Z. The flow is something like:

Command 1 writes its output to pipe_A,
  command 2 reads input from pipe_A, then writes output to pipe_Z, then
  command 3 reads input from pipe_Z, then writes to standard output.

The problem is that the program gets stuck on the second wait(NULL). In my code, it's the line right after 'printf("reached\n");'. The program doesn't terminate, and is stuck until I send an interrupt.

If I replace all three commands with the same command "echo hello", it doesn't do much but the program ends at least.

I've written a smaller program (same structure) with only two commands ("echo hello" and "wc") and it also gets stuck, just on the first wait(NULL). However, I've noticed that if I call execvp on the second command in the main program, the output is printed as expected. However, the program also terminates immediately (because of execvp), so this isn't how I want to do it.

I suspect I'm making a very obvious mistake because of lack of understanding either how pipes work or how the wait(NULL) function call works.

int main(){

```
//### COMMANDS AS STRING ARRAYS ###

    char * cmds1[3] = {"echo","hello", NULL};
    char * cmds2[3] = {"cat","-",NULL};
    char * cmds3[3] = {"wc", NULL};

//### CREATING PIPES ###

    int pipe_A[2];
    int pipe_Z[2];

    pipe(pipe_A);
    pipe(pipe_Z);

//### FIRST FORK FOR FIRST EXECVP ###

    int pid = fork();

    //Child process
    if(pid==0){

        close(pipe_A[0]);
        dup2(pipe_A[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

        execvp(cmds1[0],cmds1);
        exit(1);

    }

    //Parent process
    else if(pid >0){
        wait(NULL);
    }

//### SECOND FORK FOR SECOND EXECVP ###

    int pid2 = fork();

    //Child process
    if(pid2==0){

        close(pipe_A[1]);
        dup2(pipe_A[0],STDIN_FILENO);

        close(pipe_Z[0]);
        dup2(pipe_Z[1], STDOUT_FILENO); 

        execvp(cmds2[0],cmds2);
        exit(1);

    }

    //Parent process
    else if(pid2>0){

        printf("reached\n");
        wait(NULL);

    }

//### THIRD FORK FOR THIRD EXECVP ###

    int pid3 = fork();

    //Child process
    if(pid3==0){

        close(pipe_Z[1]);
        dup2(pipe_Z[0],STDIN_FILENO);

        execvp(cmds3[0],cmds3);
        exit(1);

    }

    //Parent process
    else if(pid2 >0){

        wait(NULL);

    }


//### END OF PROGRAM ###

    return 0;
```

}

Expected output is "1 1 6", but program does not terminate.

Comment: Without looking at your code, I would guess that you aren't closing all the file descriptors.

Comment: Looking at your code confirms that!  The parent is holding open the pipes, so the commands that are reading from the pipe are waiting for data rather than exiting.  Close the write ends of the pipe in the parent as well as the children.

Comment: Also, when you do a `dup2`, you need to close the dup'd fd.  The template is `dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO); close( fd[0]); close(fd[1])`.  (Close them both.)

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  Amongst other reasons, it is missing the necessary `#include` statements for the needed header files

Comment: Note: for code to be displayed as code. it must be indented (at least) 4 spaces.

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD`.

Comment: Additionally, as others said, you need to close both ends of each pipe in the parent process as none of the children will get EOF until _all_ processes with the pipe open for writing close the pipe.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks! I tried it and it works for my program. However, as an additional question, since I'm closing the writing end of the pipe in the parent, does that completely prevent me from being able to write to that same pipe later on?

My goal is to replicate the general structure of the code I've posted in a while loop so I can loop through an array of commands and pipe each command to the next

Comment: @user3629249 thank you, I'm sorry for any mistakes in the code (I made some slight changes while posting), but I intentionally didn't include the headers to make the code slightly less long or complicated, I'll include them next time

Comment: One of the many results of calling `fork()` is that all open file descriptors are also dup'ed in the child.

Comment: @Aiman That is correct.  If you close the write end of the pipe, you cannot write to it.  If you leave it open, any process reading from it will block on a read.  The utilities that you are calling will not exit until that pipe is closed.  If you want to write more data to a child, open a second pipe or use some other IPC mechanism.  If you want to chain N processes together, you will need N-1 pipes.  The parent doesn't need to write to any of them, and should close both ends of each soon after forking.

Answer (score 3):

You're not closing the write ends of the pipes in the parent process, so none of them ever really close all the way, so none of the children ever get EOF, so none of the children (except `echo` which doesn't read input) ever exit.

Answer (score 1):

you say:

> ... while the parent waits for execvp to finish

and `wait(2)` **never waits** for the `execvp(2)` system call to finish, but to the whole program started by `execvp(2)` to finish.

BTW, `execvp(2)` doesn't return in case of no error.  A good thing is to show in `stderr` why it failed, instead of making a `exit(1)`, because the exit code is sheldom checked by a user, and you'll not know what happened.  Something like

```
execvp(...);
fprintf(stderr, "EXECVP: %s: %s\n", cmds?[0], strerror(errno));
exit(1);
```

would be far much effective.  It just starts another program in the current process, the child you `fork()`ed from the parent.

- Your first problem is that you leave the unused file descriptors open in the parent, so the reader process of a pipe will get stuck waiting for more input until the writing side of the pipe gets closed **by all processes that have it open for writing** (and this includes the parent).  You create the pipes in the parent process, and so, you get them also on the children.  In the children you `close(2)` the not used side of the pipe, but you don't do the same in the parent (and you must, before the wait) so the reading children will receive the end of file when the writer side closes the writing side, because then, **there's no more writer processes (like now is the parent)**
- Second, this is a simple case in which the three processes will forcely end in sequence, but even in this case, you are waiting for them to finish before launching the next processes.  As processes are interrelated, only after them all have had a chance to exchange info.  In that case, you are waiting for one to finish before launching the second, and the second will not be reading anything until it is alive.  In your case, the first `wait(2)` is waiting for the first child to exit, but the first child cannot `close(2)` (it is blocked in the close) because nobody has opened the pipe for reading (well, the parent did, but the process expected to be reading that info is the second child).  If you wait for the first process to die, both processed will never be alive at the same time, because you wait for the first to end before spawning the second.

The better is to wait for them all at the end... as you say, you have made three **successful** `fork()`s, so you have to do three `wait()`s to properly end.  In that case

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) wait(NULL);
```

is correct (but at the end).  (even if any fork was not successful, the wait will detect this and fail with an error, so you don't have to check for errors)